# JSSOR two sliders on a single page?

Tags: jssor

Hello I am trying to create a webpage that has two image sections.  I would like to use you slider for each image section.  The first one loads ok but the second one doesn't. i keep getting this error:

JSSOR Uncaught Error: prototype of 'thumbnavigator' not defined

I know from a similar post that you cant have a 2nd container with the same name.

I tried changing the 2nd slider id to "slider2_container" but that didn't work.

Is there any way for me put two sliders on a single page?

any help would be appreciated as I don't really want to start all over again with a different slider.

the slider Im using is the one on the top of this page
http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html

Comment: Please post html and javascript code for the 2 sliders here.

Comment: This is most likely thumbnail navigator UI definition error. Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-thumbnail-navigator-jquery.html